# Complex query in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a model `Follow`:

```
class Follow(BaseModel):

    follower = django.db.models.ForeignKey(
        'User',
        related_name='_follows_we_are_follower'
    )
    followee = django.db.models.ForeignKey(
        'User',
        related_name='_follows_we_are_followee'
    )
    datetime_canceled = django.db.models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

When I'm handling a user, how do I get all the users he's following? I assume I want something like "Give me all the users for which exists a Follow object with a `datetime_canceled` of `None`, and the `follower` is that user, and then for all those follows get me the users that are in the `followee` field." How do I write this in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_user._follows_we_are_follower.filter(datetime_canceled=None)
```

**Edit**

```
User.objects.filter(_follows_we_are_followee__follower=my_user, _follows_we_are_followee__datetime_canceled=None)
```

Comment: This returns the follows. We need the users.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite away  from django now So, syntax would be wrong. But I guess you want something like this:

```
User.objects.filter(Follow_related_name__in = ['_follows_we_are_follower', ,'_follows_we_are_followee'], datetime_canceled__is_null =True)
```